# How can I check if my Webservice is working with Runscope and random strings?

Tags: web-services, runscope

I have a very basic check if my webservice is still up and running by sending a query to `my-endpoint.com?heartbeat={{utc_datetime}}`. The service simply returns the value of `heartbeat`.

However, if I set the Assertion

```
Text Body equals {{utc_datetime}}
```

this fails, as it is a few milliseconds different. How can I use the same variable that was send on http://runscope.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Initial Variable (expand the Environment settings at the top of the test editor) with a name like `date` and a value of `{{utc_datetime}}`. That will create a static value you can reference throughout the test using `{{date}}`.

Comment: It works. Nice that you help your users via StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to email us help@runscope.com for quicker responses.